# Loading Ajax in onload event of iframe

Tags: javascript, ajax, iframe

I'm trying to load an Ajax page on a onload event in an iframe (if possible?).

So I have an iframe:

```
<iframe onload="loadIjax('ipage','./page.php');"> <div id="ipage"></div> </iframe>
```

And Javascript

```
function loadIjax(divId,strURL)
 {

 if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{// code for IE6, IE5
xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
  {
  // show ajax response
  parent.document.getElementById(divID).innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
  }
 }
 xmlhttp.open("GET",strURL,true);
 xmlhttp.send();
 }
```

So the idea is to load page.php inside the iframe when the page is loaded.

My question, is this even possible what've written so far ? It doesn't work at this point. The problem is that Javascript doesn't find the div in the iframe. It does work if I put the same div outside of the iframe.

Answer (score 0):

Putting HTML inside an iframe tag does nothing. It's incorrect HTML.

Iframes contain a full page inside of them. That means they have their own `window` and `document`. So when you call `document.getElementById` you're doing it in the parent window, not inside the iframe. What you need to do is look for an element inside the iframe going through its document. You can do that by accessing the iframe's `contentWindow` property:

```
var iframe = document.getElementById('myIframeId');
iframe.contentWindow.document.getElementById('containerId').innerHTML = 'foo';
```

Comment: I tried it but I'm still getting an error on the iframe.contentWindow part. Javascript keeps returning that it doesn't find the div inside the iframe.

Comment: It won't if it's not there. And it won't be unless: a) you load a page in the iframe that has a div with that ID; or b) create the div and append it to the iframe's `document.body`.

Comment: Yes that seems to be the problem. I tried a) but doesn't seem to be working. Where can I read more about b) or how should I do this ?

Comment: Are you sure you simply don't need to load a new page in the iframe? You can do that by changing the iframe's `src` attribute.

Comment: that was indeed the better solution I didn't think about somehow. thanks